# Compute system response to time-varying input by odeint (or solve_ivp)

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I’m trying to solve a simple ODE to visualise the temporal response, which works well for constant input conditions using the new `solve_ivp` integration API in SciPy. For example:

```
def dN1_dt_simple(t, N1):
    return -100 * N1

sol = solve_ivp(fun=dN1_dt_simple, t_span=[0, 100e-3], y0=[N0,])
```

However, I wonder is it possible to plot the response to a time-varying input? For instance, rather than having `y0` fixed at `N0`, can I find the response to a simple sinusoid?

Is there a compatible way to pass time-varying input conditions into the API?

Comment: Do you mean something like `def dN1_dt(t, N1): return -100*N1 + np.sin(t)`?

Comment: Yes, I think so. That looks embarrassingly simple! Thanks. Would it be possible to just get the response to the first cycle however, so I can see how the system decays?

Comment: You could use `t_span = [0, T]`, where `T` is the period of the time-varying input, e.g. `2*pi` for sint(t).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although I'm interested in the longer term decay. i.e. if I excited a system with one cycle, what happens for some time period after that cycle ends. Is that possible with this API?

Comment: The accepted answer is one option.  Another option is to solve the system in two steps: take the output after one period and then solve the system again, using the final state of the first part as the initial condition to the system with the periodic input turned off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you pass to `solve_ivp` has a `t` in its signature for exactly this reason. You can do with it whatever you like¹. For example, to get a smooth, one-time pulse, you can do:

```
from numpy import pi, cos

def fun(t,N1):
    input = 1-cos(t) if 0<t<2*pi else 0
    return -100*N1 + input

sol = solve_ivp(fun=fun, t_span=[0,20], y0=[N0])
```

Note that `y0` is not the input in your use of the term, but the initial condition. It is defined and makes sense for one point in time only – where you start your integration/simulation.
With ODEs, you typically model external inputs as forces or similar (affecting the time derivative of the system like in the above example) rather than direct changes to the state.
With this approach and in your context of an excitable system, `N0` is already the outcome of some external input.

---

<sup>¹ As long as it is sufficiently smooth for the needs of the respective integrator, usually continuously differentiable (C¹). If you want to implement a step, better use a very sharp [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) instead.</sup>